# Nullity of a linear transformation $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> T is a projection onto the vector    $v = (1, 2, 2)$ given by
>   $$T(x,y,z) = \frac{x+2y+2z}{9} \cdot (1, 2, 2)$$
>   Use the given information to find the nullity of $T$.

I know the nullity of $T$ is determined by $$x+2y+2z= 0$$ 
Is there a systematic way of finding the nullity of $T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single non-trivial linear relation in a three-dimensional space determines a plane. Thought differently, there are three variables and one constraint, so there are two free variables. And so the nullity is $2$.

Implicitly, I'm thinking of the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: is there a systematic way. I can show this through calculation?

Comment: Sure. Write a basis for the nullspace. This amounts to row reducing a matrix in the general case, thoughbit can be done more simply here.